# I am a beginner in html and my code is not working

Tags: html, windows, web, web-applications, social-media

I am currently a beginner in html and I have seen this problem many times and I do not know how to solve it. I copied a source code from a video in an attempt to make a social media. The following code is in the file **home.html**:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
home
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
{{hello}}
<br>
{{user}}
{% endblock content %}

{% block scripts %}
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log('working')
})
</script>
{% endblock scripts %}
```

However, in the video the html page seems correct and all buttons and functions are working. On the other side my html page is like this:

[...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1ONa.png)

Answer (score 0):

The guide you have seen concerns Flask, a framework for applications written in Python. The code will not work because there is no preprocessor that can process it. In this case the browser will show you plain text without formatting.

Comment: I see, so oi would have to install Flask, right?

Comment: Yes, and configure your project to should work with Flask and basic configuration.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help I will now try and do that

Comment: Close question and give me best answer, thanks :)